# Objective C array of UIButtons (including taking care of initialization, action, etc.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

I have difficulties with make an array of UI Buttons rather than having many separate ones. I'm trying to create four and have:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *b0;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b3;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *b0;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *b1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *b2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *b3;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)b0Click:(id)sender {
    //Do something
}

- (IBAction)b1Click:(id)sender {
    //Do something
}

- (IBAction)b2Click:(id)sender {
    //Do something
}

- (IBAction)b3Click:(id)sender {
    //Do something
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't describe the problem (where is the array? what doesn't it do?). Have you looked at `IBOutletCollection`?

Comment: Are you trying to create them from interface builder? If so you aren't creating outlets that point to your references. Also check out `IBOutletCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `IBOutletCollection`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) buttons;
```

Now connect all your buttons to this collection.

You can now accessing the buttons by:

```
[self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^ (UIButton* button, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop) {
//Do stuff here
}];
```

I must warn you against making assumptions about the order of the buttons inside the array. It is better to give each button a tag, and then in the action method decide which code path to take according to their tag.